# Passing list of object as proptype

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can declare that a prop is an instance of a class. This uses
JS's instanceof operator.

```
  optionalMessage: PropTypes.instanceOf(Message)
```

Is there a way to declare a list of Message class like following ? Any solution to this ?

```
  optionalMessage: PropTypes.ListOf(Message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
optionalMessage: PropTypes.arrayOf(
   PropTypes.shape({
     classProp1: PropTypes.string,
     classProp2: PropTypes.number,
     classProp3: PropTypes.bool
   })
)
```

Edit: Rendering this type of data in render function

```
render() { 
    const { optionalMessage } = this.props;
    return () {
        <div>
            {optionalMessage.map(item => (
                 <li>{item.classProp1} - {item.classProp2}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you pls tell me how we can iterate such a list in render ?

Comment: render() { 
    const { optionalMessage } = this.props;
    return () {
        <div>
            {optionalMessage.map(item => (
                 <li>{item.classProp1} - {item.classProp2}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
    }
}